# Is there a way to find the oldest modified file in a directory with only the find command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

I'm doing a linux exercice and I have to look through a directory and find the oldest modified file and it's directory. I can't seem to be able to do it using only the find command without any pipes and or scripts... Is there a way?

I tried commands like

```
find archive -type f -exec stat -c "%Y %n" {} \; -print
```

and

```
find ~/archive -type f -exec stat -c "%Y" {} +
```

but they don't really give me what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it only with `find`. You'll need to pipe the output to other commands like `sort` and `head`.

Comment: If this is a class assignment, did they give a lesson first with clues about how you should approach something like this?

Comment: You can try running `find -mtime +200` and play with the number to find the oldest modified file. The number represents the number of days, the `+` means the file must be older than that.

Comment: my only clue is that the find command and it's ACTIONS are considered to be ONE command. Also `find -mtime +200` doesn't work since the directory has a loooot of files that are older

Comment: Edit: I don't have to necessarily use the `find` command but since it's in my clues I figured it would be the easiest way but I guess not hahaha

Comment: for now all I have is `find ~/archive/ -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \;` and it only gives me the lat modified time of every file. I just need to find a way to sort it and get the oldest one which seems impossbile without `sort` and `head`